# Swift: Search string in sentence in Array

Tags: arrays, swift

I am developing search textfield. I have an array of Strings that looks like this....

```
var keywords:[String] = ["dance, music and hippo", "apple juice, tomato"]
```

I tried to use function contains but its not doing well.

```
for i in 0..<keywordsArr.count {
    if(!keywordsArr[i].contains(searchTextField.text!)){
        print("removed \(keywordsArr[i])")
        keywordsArr.removeAtIndex(i)
    }
}
```

this is extension that i am using.

```
extension String {

    func contains(find: String) -> Bool{
        return self.rangeOfString(find) != nil
    }
}
```

the result should be i am calling function with text: "music" and it should return index of that string

Comment: You are mutating the array while you are iterating it. That may cause some issue. Usually in that case, we do a reverse iteration (starting from the end).

Comment: Oh thank you i updated my code :-)

Comment: @PanMluvčí could you roll back your edit, you shouldn't update your question to contain the answer, that's what the answers are for. This way your question is more likely to be useful for future visitors.

Comment: I did it...thx for remind :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this very succinctly, using `filter`, which returns an array with only elements for which the closure holds. You should also use optional binding to avoid using a force unwrap of `searchTextField.text`

```
if let text = searchTextField.text {
    keywordsArr = keywordsArr.filter { $0.contains(text) }
}
```

Comment: Oh your method is even faster and cleaner than mine :-) thank you for posting.

Answer (score 0):

First you shouldn't edit the array size inside the loop, because each time you iterate you recalculate its size with "keywordsArr.count", and that will cause an exception 
 You can use those few lines to return the index of the string if it's contained in your array, or -1 if not. 
 good luck

```
func doesContain(array:[String], searchString:String) -> Int {
    let size = array.count

    for i in 0..<size {
        if array[i].rangeOfString(searchString) != nil {
            print("exists")
            print("removed \(array[i])")
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
var keywords:[String] = ["dance, music and hippo", "apple juice, tomato"]

doesContain(keywords, searchString: "music")
```